# Change the value of object field in driver editor with python script

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I try to change the object name field of my driver with python script but I cant access to data path name of object name to change that with python
in this image I need to change object name from 1 to any other object

[image: Text]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example code snippet, to set the target.id to the desired destination object *dest* which is changing variable pointing to an object, specific to your "World" custom property "prop1":

```
import bpy

dest = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']

d = bpy.data.worlds['World'].animation_data.drivers[0]
var = d.driver.variables[0]
var.targets[0].id = dest
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: the OP is a Blender beginner, so maybe it would be helpful to explain, how he can use that snippet in a driver ;) anyway +1 ;)

Comment: I am confused because this code is works in my demo file but not works in my main project ! .... where can i find any document for example the codes " .animation_data.drivers " in internet ? thanks

Comment: @jackon -- perhaps it's because I made the assumption that ```drivers[0]``` is the one your want to reverence, and the same for ```.variables[0]```.  You could look further by searching this site with "[python] drivers".  Also be sure that you have bpy.data.worlds['World'] containing something useful (your *World* might be labelled something else).